# The alert dialog disappears

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I want to do an `alert dialog` in an Android app. When I put the `setPositiveButton` and `setNegativeButton` all is right but when I click on the background, the alert dialog 
disappears and this functionality I don't want it. 
I need that the user only can choose two possibilities and when the user touch the background, the alert dialog doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent dialog box from getting dismissed on back key pressed use this

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

And to prevent outside touch use this

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure your AlertDialog is not cancelable.

```
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
```

Check the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setCancelable(boolean)).